# Error retrieving adverse events by country

Tags: api, openfda

I was using a query like this one  [https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=patient.drug.medicinalproduct.exact:("ELIQUIS")+AND+receivedate:[20110101+TO+20151231]%27+AND+occurcountry:%27fr%27&count=serious](https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=patient.drug.medicinalproduct.exact:(%22ELIQUIS%22)+AND+receivedate:%5B20110101+TO+20151231%5D%27+AND+occurcountry:%27fr%27&count=serious) to retrieve all adverse events for a specific country.
It was working some month ago. But now it seems the searchable fields occurcountry doesn't work anymore. When I deleted it the query works. It is an bug  or I missed an update for the API?

Answer (score 1):

You have an extraneous single quotation mark right after the closing `]`, which is breaking the query's syntax. Here is the corrected URL:

[https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=patient.drug.medicinalproduct.exact:("ELIQUIS")+AND+receivedate:[20110101+TO+20151231]+AND+occurcountry:'fr'&count=serious](https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=patient.drug.medicinalproduct.exact:(%22ELIQUIS%22)%20AND%20receivedate:%5B20110101%20TO%2020151231%5D%20AND%20occurcountry:%27fr%27&count=serious)